# Hibernate's sessionFactory overwrites initialState entity after merge

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm using Springboot and Hibernate in a project and I'm doing a PATCH request.
Long story short, I invoke an update with:

```
hibernateEntityAccess.update(original, patchedData, OperationTarget.ENTITY);
```

This is the update invoked:

```
    @SyncChs
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void update(final Auditable<?> initialState, final Auditable<?> finalState, final OperationTarget target, final boolean isInternalOperation) throws IOException {
        int key = operation.getCurrentSession().setInitial(initialState, (AuditableEntity) initialState, target, isInternalOperation);
        Auditable<?> merged = (Auditable<?>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(finalState);
        operation.getCurrentSession().setFinal(key, merged, (AuditableEntity) finalState, isInternalOperation);
    }
```

After `.merge(finalState)`, the data in `original` is overwritten with the data that was in `patchedData`.
I've made my entities clonable and tried this

```
hibernateEntityAccess.update(original.clone(), patchedData.clone(), OperationTarget.ENTITY);
```

to see if `original` variable would not be overwritten by merge but the same behavior occurred.

Does anyone have an idea of why this happens?

Comment: that is expected: I believe you have retrieved `initialState` via `em.find` or something similar, so actual state get stored in persistent context and HBN modifies that state when performing `merge`. Call `em.detach(initialState)` before calling `update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by using .toBuilder().build():

```
hibernateEntityAccess.update(original.toBuilder().build(), patchedData.toBuilder().build(), OperationTarget.ENTITY);
```

This way my original variables didn't change.